# iTextSharp - set Splitlate for only one cell / row

Tags: c#, itext

For my next problem, i have to explain a bit more. :-D

In my current project im trying to create an invoice-pdf with C#.

As you can see at my last Question, itried to add subtotals. Bruno helped me to sucsess. On every footer in my positionTable, the subtotal is added except on the last one because of

```
positionTable.SkipLastFooter = true;
```

In my positionTable there can be long positions so i set the table to

```
positionTable.SplitLate = false;
```

Now im trying to add the total box on the last page. For that i created an additional table (totalTable). The table should always be keeped together. So i set

```
totalTable.KeepTogether = true;
```

First problem was, if the totalTable would not fit to the page, it would be on the next page. But the positiontable is already closed and no subtotal would be shown on previous page.

So i decided to nest my totalTable into my positionTable. I wondered as i saw, that `totalTable.KeepTogether = true` does not longer has any effect.

Is there a solution to set one single cell to `SplitLate = false;`?

`+------------------------------------------+
| Pos | Menge | Text | Einzelpreis | Summe |
+------------------------------------------+
|  1  |   2   | Text |       10.00 | 20.00 |
+------------------------------------------+
|  2  |   1   | Text |       10.00 | 10.00 |
+------------------------------------------+
|  3  |   4   | Text |       10.00 | 40.00 |
+------------------------------------------+
|  4  |   2   | Text |       10.00 | 20.00 |
+==========================================+
|Sum without Tax                   | 90.00 |
|15% Tax                           | 13.50 |
|Total                             |103.50 |
+==========================================+`

Comment: I understand your question, but it's a difficult one. I know it can be done, but I don't like the current solution I have in mind, so I'm waiting for inspiration to think of a better solution. If I don't answer before Sunday night, please write a comment with @BrunoLowagie to remind me.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie This is the reminder you whanted. :-D

Comment: OK, I had so many other things to do this weekend that I completely forgot about this question. I'll see what I can do today.

Comment: I have tried adapting my initial example ([SubTotal](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/tables/using-cell-events-add-special-content#2887-subtotal.java)) and while it wouldn't be that difficult to solve the edge case in case you change the 50 rows to 92 rows, it turns out to be very difficult if you change the 50 rows to 93 rows (in which case the table fits, but there's no more room to add an extra footer row). It would take too much time for me to pursue the quest for an answer. I will have to pass. You will have to find someone with more time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**New answer:**

As indicated in the comments, you could add all rows at absolute positions using `writeSelectedRows()`:

```
package sandbox.tables;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Element;
import com.itextpdf.text.Phrase;
import com.itextpdf.text.Rectangle;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfContentByte;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPCell;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPCellEvent;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

import sandbox.WrapToTest;

@WrapToTest
public class SubTotal3 {

    public static final String DEST = "results/tables/subtotal3.pdf";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,
            DocumentException {
        File file = new File(DEST);
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        new SubTotal3().createPdf(DEST);
    }

    class Totals {

        double subtotal = 0;
        double total = 0;
        boolean done;
    }

    class SubTotalEvent implements PdfPCellEvent {

        Double price;
        Totals totals;

        public SubTotalEvent(Totals totals, double price) {
            this.totals = totals;
            this.price = price;
        }

        public SubTotalEvent(Totals totals) {
            this.totals = totals;
            price = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void cellLayout(PdfPCell cell, Rectangle position, PdfContentByte[] canvases) {
            if (totals.done) {
                PdfContentByte canvas = canvases[PdfPTable.TEXTCANVAS];
                ColumnText.showTextAligned(canvas, Element.ALIGN_LEFT,
                        new Phrase(String.valueOf(totals.total)),
                        position.getLeft() + 2, position.getBottom() + 2, 0);
                totals.total = totals.total * 1.15;
                return;
            }
            if (price == null) {
                PdfContentByte canvas = canvases[PdfPTable.TEXTCANVAS];
                ColumnText.showTextAligned(canvas, Element.ALIGN_LEFT,
                        new Phrase(String.valueOf(totals.subtotal)),
                        position.getLeft() + 2, position.getBottom() + 2, 0);
                totals.subtotal = 0;
                return;
            }
            totals.subtotal += price;
            totals.total += price;
        }

    }

    public void createPdf(String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {

        int rows = 92;
        Totals totals = new Totals();

        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
        document.open();
        float width = document.right() - document.left();

        // header
        PdfPTable header = new PdfPTable(5);
        header.setWidths(new int[]{1, 1, 1, 3, 3});
        header.setTotalWidth(width);
        header.addCell("Pos");
        header.addCell("Menge");
        header.addCell("Text");
        header.addCell("Einzerpreis");
        header.addCell("Summe");
        // definitions
        PdfPTable footer = new PdfPTable(5);
        footer.setWidths(new int[]{1, 1, 1, 3, 3});
        footer.setTotalWidth(width);
        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Subtotal"));
        cell.setColspan(4);
        footer.addCell(cell);
        cell = new PdfPCell();
        cell.setCellEvent(new SubTotal3.SubTotalEvent(totals));
        footer.addCell(cell);

        // actual table
        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(5);
        table.setWidths(new int[]{1, 1, 1, 3, 3});
        table.setTotalWidth(width);
        // table body
        for (int r = 0; r < rows;) {
            table.addCell(String.valueOf(++r));
            table.addCell("1");
            table.addCell("text");
            table.addCell("10.0");
            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("10.0"));
            cell.setCellEvent(new SubTotalEvent(totals, 10));
            table.addCell(cell);
        }

        // extra footer
        PdfPTable total = new PdfPTable(5);
        total.setWidths(new int[]{1, 1, 1, 3, 3});
        total.setTotalWidth(width);
        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Total (excl. vat)"));
        cell.setColspan(4);
        total.addCell(cell);
        cell = new PdfPCell();
        cell.setCellEvent(new SubTotal3.SubTotalEvent(totals));
        total.addCell(cell);
        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("VAT"));
        cell.setColspan(4);
        total.addCell(cell);
        total.addCell("15%");
        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Total (incl. vat)"));
        cell.setColspan(4);
        total.addCell(cell);
        cell = new PdfPCell();
        cell.setCellEvent(new SubTotal3.SubTotalEvent(totals));
        total.addCell(cell);

        PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
        float availableHeight = document.top() - document.bottom()
            - footer.getTotalHeight() - footer.getTotalHeight();
        int start = 0;
        float left = document.left();
        float pos = document.top();
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; ) {
            pos = header.writeSelectedRows(0, -1, left, pos, cb);
            float height = 0;
            while (height < availableHeight && i < rows) {
                height += table.getRowHeight(i++);
            }
            if (height >= availableHeight) i--;
            pos = table.writeSelectedRows(start, i, left, pos, cb);
            start = i;
            height += total.getTotalHeight();
            if (i == rows) {
                if (height > availableHeight) {
                    footer.writeSelectedRows(0, -1, left, pos, cb);
                    document.newPage();
                    pos = document.top();
                }
                totals.done = true;
                total.writeSelectedRows(0, -1, left, pos, cb);
            }
            else {
                footer.writeSelectedRows(0, -1, left, pos, cb);
                document.newPage();
                pos = document.top();
            }
        }

        document.close();
    }
}
```

**Previous answer:**

This is the code I eventually ended up with. I share it for what it's worth:

```
package sandbox.tables;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Element;
import com.itextpdf.text.Phrase;
import com.itextpdf.text.Rectangle;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfContentByte;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPCell;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPCellEvent;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

public class SubTotal2 {

    public static final String DEST = "results/tables/subtotal2.pdf";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,
            DocumentException {
        File file = new File(DEST);
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        new SubTotal2().createPdf(DEST);
    }

    class Totals {

        double subtotal = 0;
        double total = 0;
    }

    class SubTotalEvent implements PdfPCellEvent {

        Double price;
        Totals totals;

        public SubTotalEvent(Totals totals, double price) {
            this.totals = totals;
            this.price = price;
        }

        public SubTotalEvent(Totals totals) {
            this.totals = totals;
            price = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void cellLayout(PdfPCell cell, Rectangle position, PdfContentByte[] canvases) {
            if (price == null) {
                PdfContentByte canvas = canvases[PdfPTable.TEXTCANVAS];
                ColumnText.showTextAligned(canvas, Element.ALIGN_LEFT,
                        new Phrase(String.valueOf(totals.subtotal)),
                        position.getLeft() + 2, position.getBottom() + 2, 0);
                totals.subtotal = 0;
                return;
            }
            totals.subtotal += price;
            totals.total += price;
        }

    }

    public void createPdf(String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {

        Totals totals = new Totals();

        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
        document.open();
        // actual table
        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(5);
        table.setWidths(new int[]{1, 1, 1, 3, 3});
        // header
        table.addCell("Pos");
        table.addCell("Menge");
        table.addCell("Text");
        table.addCell("Einzerpreis");
        table.addCell("Summe");
        // definitions
        table.setHeaderRows(1);
        table.setComplete(false);
        PdfPCell cell;
        float threshold = 55;
        // table body
        for (int r = 0; r < 92;) {
            table.addCell(String.valueOf(++r));
            table.addCell("1");
            table.addCell("text");
            table.addCell("10.0");
            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("10.0"));
            cell.setCellEvent(new SubTotalEvent(totals, 10));
            table.addCell(cell);
            document.add(table);
            if (writer.getVerticalPosition(false) < threshold) {
                cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Subtotal"));
                cell.setColspan(4);
                table.addCell(cell);
                cell = new PdfPCell();
                cell.setCellEvent(new SubTotal2.SubTotalEvent(totals));
                table.addCell(cell);
            }
        }
        // extra footer
        PdfPTable tTable = new PdfPTable(5);
        tTable.setKeepTogether(true);
        tTable.setWidths(new int[]{1, 1, 1, 3, 3});
        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Total (excl. vat)"));
        cell.setColspan(4);
        tTable.addCell(cell);
        tTable.addCell(String.valueOf(totals.total));
        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("VAT"));
        cell.setColspan(4);
        tTable.addCell(cell);
        tTable.addCell("15%");
        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Total (incl. vat)"));
        cell.setColspan(4);
        tTable.addCell(cell);
        tTable.addCell(String.valueOf(totals.total * 1.15));
        tTable.setTotalWidth(table.getTotalWidth());
        if (
            writer.getVerticalPosition(false) >= threshold &&
            writer.getVerticalPosition(false) < document.bottom() + tTable.getTotalHeight()) {
            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Subtotal"));
            cell.setColspan(4);
            table.addCell(cell);
            cell = new PdfPCell();
            cell.setCellEvent(new SubTotal2.SubTotalEvent(totals));
            table.addCell(cell);
        }
        table.setComplete(true);
        document.add(table);
        document.add(tTable);
        document.close();
    }
}
```

There's some dark magic in this code: the value of `threshold` was determined with trial and error. It's a Y position that defines at which Y position we decide that a footer is needed. It wasn't a complete guess: you can take Y position of the bottom margin (36), add the height of a single row (16) and add sufficient space, making sure you don't exceed the bottom margin to which you add the height of two rows.

Don't define a footer, just add the table row by row, and check the Y position after every row. If the threshold is reached (`writer.getVerticalPosition(false) < threshold`), add a footer.

Now we are adding a footer each time we're close to the end of the page, but no footer is added if we are not that close to the bottom margin, but close enough so that a new page is needed for the table with the totals (`writer.getVerticalPosition(false) >= threshold && writer.getVerticalPosition(false) < document.bottom() + tTable.getTotalHeight()`). In that case, we also need to add the extra footer row.

You can test this example by changing the value `92` to `89`, `90`, `91`, `93`, and `94`. It works, but it's tricky code.

Comment: One might consider introducing a concept of a "table splitting strategy" class (which decides on where to split tables) which can be customised.

Comment: Thank you very mutch for your fast answer! :-)
I guess there is another problem at this solution. We cant print row by row and print footer manualy because the sigle rows can have more than one line in the text.

Comment: @MartinS. I think you'll have to consider abandoning the idea of a large table with all the data. Instead, you'll have to consider using many different tables that are added to the document using `ColumnText`. With `ColumnText`, you can add content to a document in *simulation mode* and get information about the Y position. Based on that information, you can decide if you want to add the content *for real*, or if you want to move to a new page. This implies that you are responsible for adding a table header (and footer) for each new page.

Comment: Okay, i will try. But thank you for your Help! I guess wasn't an easy question.

Comment: Now that I think of it: using `writeSelectedRows()` could be easier than using `ColumnText`. If you use `setTotalWidth()`, you can ask each row for its height. This means you can calculate how many rows fit on a page, and then decide which rows you want to add on the current page (at an absolute position), and which should be forwarded to the next page. In this case, you'll also have to add the header and footer separately to each page (also with `writeSelectedRows()`).

Comment: @MartinS. Please take a look at the extra code sample I added to my answer.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie I will try this tomorrow and give you feedback.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie I tried it and its close to that i need. But now, if a row contains some breaks, its possible that it flows over the end of the page.

The best solution up to now was in the beginning. Position-Table with `table.SplitLate = false;` and `table.SkipLastFooter = true;`. And after that the total-table with `table.KeepTogether = true;`. Maybe im taking this solution with the Compromise not to have a subtotal if total-Table breaks to next page if i dont find a better solution.

Comment: At first, I didn't understand your comment. Now that I've taken a second look at my code, I see that there's an `i--` missing. Add `i--` right before `pos = table.writeSelectedRows(start, i, left, pos, cb);` and your problem will be solved.

Comment: Just ignore my old comment. :-D

If i add a `i--` at this point the loop will run infinite.
It's in the loop `for (int i = 0; i<rows; ) {`

Comment: Let me give it a try. I already adapted the code sample like this: `if (height >= availableHeight) i--;`. I think we're close. It's merely a matter of Math.

Comment: Yep, adding `if (height >= availableHeight)` solves the infinite loop (and the problem with rows that drop from the page).

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Thank you very mutch! Its a great solution. The only thing witch does not work is, a row in a table is always keeped together. There is no splitting to next page for a long text in a table row. But you cant get everything! ;-)
I thank you very mutch Bruno